# How can I optimise Range Set and .Value

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a more efficient way of writing the following:

```
Private Sub ConvertDatesToValue_Click()

Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range

Set Rng1 = Range("Q8:Q12")
Set Rng2 = Range("Q16:Q20")
Set Rng3 = Range("T8:T12")
Set Rng4 = Range("T16:T20")

Rng1.Value = Rng1.Value
Rng2.Value = Rng2.Value
Rng3.Value = Rng3.Value
Rng4.Value = Rng4.Value

End Sub
```

It looks and feels a bit janky.

Comment: Where is that code located? Is it a `UserForm` or a `Worksheet` module's code-behind?

Comment: can't you just convert the whole area `Q8:T20` to values ? `[Q8:T20] = [Q8:T20].Value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Private Sub ConvertDatesToValue_Click()
> ```

So we're looking at a control's `Click` handler, presumably an ActiveX button on a worksheet, in which case we're in that worksheet's code-behind module.

The button means to invoke a command that will convert the formulas with their value in a specific range of cells that contain dates.

I would start with a procedure that's responsible for assigning `Range.Value` onto itself, given a `Range`:

```
Public Sub FreezeFormulaResult(ByVal target As Range)
    target.Value = target.Value
End Sub
```

Next we need to identify the range we'll pass into that procedure.

> ```
> Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range
>
> Set Rng1 = Range("Q8:Q12")
> Set Rng2 = Range("Q16:Q20")
> Set Rng3 = Range("T8:T12")
> Set Rng4 = Range("T16:T20")
> ```

Kudos for avoiding the implicit `Variant` trap, and declaring an explicit type for every one of these variables.

> *it looks and feels a bit janky*

That's because the variables have that numeric suffix. `Rng1...RngN` is a code smell indeed: it's a dirty solution to the problem of *needing a bunch of something*.

Often, a more elegant solution would be to use an array:

```
Dim ranges As Variant
ranges = Array(Range("Q8:Q12"), Range("Q16:Q20"), Range("T8:T12"), Range("T16:T20"))
```

There are different many ways to skin a cat, but a union'ed disjointed `Range`<sup>1</sup> will not produce the expected results. Because you need 4 distinct areas, you'll need 4 distinct operations.

*How* the click handler needs to fetch the ranges, depends on where that handler is.

---

If we're looking at an `MSForms.CommandButton` (ActiveX) button on a `Worksheet`, then the click handler is in the very same sheet we want to get the cells from.

In that case we can work off the current object, `Me` - and in fact by *not* qualifying `Range` calls we're doing *exactly* that... implicitly.

In other words this:

> ```
> Set Rng1 = Range("Q8:Q12")
> ```

Means this:

```
Set Rng1 = Me.Range("Q8:Q12")
```

You can't have a button `Click` handler in a standard module, but if you were to write this in one:

```
Set Rng1 = Range("Q8:Q12")
```

Then that would be implicity this:

```
Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("Q8:Q12")
```

Note the difference: that's why implicit code is evil, and why context is everything - by writing explicit code, you reduce the cognitive load by making the context *local* rather than *ambient*.

We need *something* that gives us an array of `Range` objects to work with. Let's try *abstraction* - it could be a public property in the sheet's code-behind:

```
Public Property Get ImportantDateRanges() As Variant
    ImportantDateRanges = Array( _
        Me.Range("Q8:Q12"), _
        Me.Range("Q16:Q20"), _
        Me.Range("T8:T12"), _
        Me.Range("T16:T20"))
End Property
```

And now the button's `Click` handler no longer needs to care what the cells are, and the *abstraction level* is just perfect:

```
Private Sub ConvertDatesToValues_Click()
    FreezeDateFormulas
End sub

Private Sub FreezeDateFormulas()

    Dim dateRanges As Variant
    dateRanges = Me.ImportantDateRanges

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(dateRanges) To UBound(dateRanges)
        FreezeFormulaResult dateRanges(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

---

If we're looking at an `MSForms.CommandButton` on a `UserForm`, it's the exact same ActiveX button, ...[but it's an entirely different story](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/), because while you don't own a `Worksheet` instance (Excel does), you *do* own a `UserForm` instance - and that comes with implications too numerous to explain here (that link goes to an article I wrote about how forms don't need to run the show).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>[How can I optimise Range Set and .Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567317/excel-vba-optimise-range-set-and-value#comment90102078_51567391)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and explanation for this. Its really appreciated and really useful to me

Answer (score 4):

Try a direct value reversion.

```
Private Sub ConvertDatesToValue_Click()

    With Worksheets("sheet9")
        .Range("Q8:Q12") = .Range("Q8:Q12").Value
        .Range("Q16:Q20") = .Range("Q16:Q20").Value
        .Range("T8:T12") = .Range("T8:T12").Value
        .Range("T16:T20") = .Range("T16:T20").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

You really should be aware of what worksheet you're on.

Comment: @Batteredburrito the idea is to capture a reference the worksheet you want to work with in the `With` block (notice the dereferencing dots before each `Range` member call) - it your macro should modify `Sheet1`, then go `With Sheet1`, or `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` if the sheet isn't in `ThisWorkbook`; If you macro means to do what it does on whatever worksheet is currently active, then go `With ActiveSheet` ;-)

Comment: There's a problem though: using union'd disjointed ranges won't produce the expected result.

Comment: and it's even more unexpected than I expected .. `.Value` returns the values of the first area `Q8:Q12` only, but somehow the top 2 areas get the values of `Q8:Q12` and the bottom 2 areas get only the `Q8` value

Comment: @MathieuGuindon,  My bad. My original tests were with simple sum formulas and I didn't notice the difference in values. After changing to address formulas, the problem was obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through the 4 areas :

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range("Q8:Q12,Q16:Q20,T8:T12,T16:T20").Areas
    r = r.Value
Next
```

Comment: This is a highly condensed version and does exactly as needed, thank you very much @Slai :)